# Copying JSON into a map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to React and I've been wrapping my head for the last hour trying to display the results of an API. I have an API returning this:

```
{
  "data": [{
      "address": "34xp4vRoCGJym3xR7yCVPFHoCNxv4Twseo",
      "balance": 17568220019863
    },
    {
      "address": "35hK24tcLEWcgNA4JxpvbkNkoAcDGqQPsP",
      "balance": 15100113065160
    },
    {
      "address": "385cR5DM96n1HvBDMzLHPYcw89fZAXULJP",
      "balance": 11530490707099
    },
    {
      "address": "3CgKHXR17eh2xCj2RGnHJHTDjPpqaNDgyT",
      "balance": 11185824585401
    },
    {
      "address": "37XuVSEpWW4trkfmvWzegTHQt7BdktSKUs",
      "balance": 9450576862072
    },
    {
      "address": "183hmJGRuTEi2YDCWy5iozY8rZtFwVgahM",
      "balance": 8594734898577
    },
    {
      "address": "1FeexV6bAHb8ybZjqQMjJrcCrHGW9sb6uF",
      "balance": 7995720088144
    },
    {
      "address": "3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r",
      "balance": 7689310178244
    }
  ],
  "context": {
    "code": 200,
    "source": "A",
    "time": 0.14749908447265625,
    "limit": 10,
    "offset": 0,
    "rows": 10,
    "pre_rows": 10,
    "total_rows": 27974300,
    "state": 601405,
    "cache": {
      "live": true,
      "duration": 60,
      "since": "2019-10-28 17:53:32",
      "until": "2019-10-28 17:54:32",
      "time": null
    }
  }
};
```

I am only interested in the address and the balance. Now, in my state I have a `richList: {}`, but I can't figure out how to copy the JSON data I'm interested in into the richList.

I have this so far but of course it doesn't work:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(apiRequest)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data.data[0]["address"])
    this.setState({
      richList: data
    })
  })
}
```

I think I need to use the map function but I can't figure out how exactly.

I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: That should work fine, assuming your component knows how to use `data` in the original format.

Comment: `richList: data.data` should give what you want.

Comment: @Nikhil It doesn't though? If I console.log richList it shows up as undefined.

Comment: @Solal - What do you get when you add `console.log(data.data);` before calling `setState()`?

Comment: @Nikhil I get the 10 addresses and balances... I don't understand why ```this.richList``` is undefined then.

Comment: Where are you calling `this.richList`? You are making an API request which is an asynchronous operation, and `this.richList` would only be available after the API results are fetched.

Comment: @Nikhil Right now I console.log it after the setState. I even put a sleep in case of but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Solal - `setState()` is also asynchronous in nature. This should be an easy fix. Try to reproduce the issue on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com), [CodePen](https://codepen.io), or a similar site, I'll take a look. You can also ask a new question and someone will answer.

Comment: To tack on to what @Nikhil was saying, setState provides an optional callback parameter. You can throw the console log in there (and it should be this.state.richList rather than this.richList). Try something like this: `this.setState({richList: data.data}, () => console.log(this.state.richList))`

Comment: @JonWarren God d*mn it was because I wrote this.richList instead of this.state.richList. I'm still new to React so I make little mistakes like this, thanks for the help! Also thanks Nikhil !